# Terrible WiFi range

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, range

My house was built in 1886, with knob & tube wiring, no ground.  My wired ethernet runs at 600MB down & 30-40 up.  Wireless is another issue.  I have a top of the line Nighthawk wireless router, currently in the master bedroom.  The WiFi signal will barely get out of the room.  The living room, 30' away, has no signal at all.  I've done all the typical troubleshooting, relocating, etc.  No help.  Is it possible the old wiring, with no ground, is affecting the signal range?  Walls are all wood lath & plaster.

Comment: Any chance there is metal in the walls? e.g. a tight metal mesh would block signal...

Comment: No, no metal mesh.  All lath is wood, with about 1/2" plaster

Comment: Switch between 2.5ghz and 5ghz (and back again) to determine which gives you more distance.  Then, you can either poke holes to get Ethernet cables across your hose.. or Extenders actually work quite well for me.  And they are cheap.

Comment: Lath and plaster typically includes wire mesh. Are you sure yours does not?

Answer (score 0):

Some choices:

- Use a mains WiFi range extender, as in [this list](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=wifi%20range%20extender), which might, or might not, work with old wiring. Many extenders do not require a grounded outlet.
- Try a [directional antenna](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00OCJYPCY), or [make your own cantenna](https://jacobsalmela.com/2013/09/07/wi-fi-cantenna-2-4ghz-how-to-make-a-long-range-wi-fi-antenna/).
- Try different channels or even a different band. [Some channels within a WiFi band are allowed more transmitting power](https://www.engeniustech.com/go-guide-channel-transmit-power-wi-fi-networks-2/), e.g. channel 36 at 5.170 GHz is 200 mW max, and channel 143 has a 900 mW limit. More important may be the band: 2.4-2.5 GHz might penetrate lathe-and-plaster better than higher frequerncies, though the low frequencies theoretically would have lower baud rates. Check your router manual for information on how to change channel and band.